# assigning function argument to an implicit global variable having similar name

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure if it is an appropriate question for this forum or not.But i am going to post it here.I have this little piece of code which i wrote to see what happens if an implicit global variable has similar name with the function argument which is assigned to it.But when i console.log the global name variable outside function's scope it prints out 'Baggins' which i have no idea from where it's comming.

```
function myfunc(name){
  name=name;//global name variable??
  console.log(name);
}
myfunc('shimanta');
console.log(name);
```

CHROME:

[image]

FIREFOX:

[image]

Comment: You verified the source of gotit.html and have no other javascript running?

Comment: i have seen the page source in chrome ..it contains exactly the same code i have posted here

Comment: To answer your question, no, the `name` variable inside the function is reference the text that you passed in, not the global `name` variable.

Comment: Can you open up the developer tools, switch to the Sources tab, use Ctrl + Shift + F and search sources for name

Comment: You do know that your screenshot isn't showing the `console`?

Comment: See "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem" and "Help others reproduce the problem" in [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the screenshot was taken with document.body.innerHTML=name; statement,but result was same

Comment: it was creating wired output like baggins.from where it is comming that question comes first.i know this title is impossible to understand .sorry for that

Comment: In what way is *"shimanta"* and *""* the same as *"shimanta"* and *"Baggins"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All variables listed in the function argument list become local variables. So the function is just setting the local variable `name` to itself. If you want to set the global variable you have to access it through the `window` object:

```js
function myfunc(name) {
  window.name = name;
  alert(name);
}
myfunc('shimanta');
alert(name);
```

Comment: why shouldn't i create a global variable without window. keyword.In firefox it's showing ""(without window keyword)

Comment: If it has the same name as the parameter, it will be a local variable, not a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is likely the use of a global variable `name`. One of the best solutions to this issue is to turn this into an object, then use that object to manage scoping in Javascript. The revised code looks almost the same:

```
var nameManager = function () {
  var self = {};
  var name = '';

  self.myfunc = function(name){
    self.name = name;
    console.log(self.name);
  };

  self.logName = function () {
    console.log(self.name);
  };

  return self;
};

var myManager = nameManager();
myManager.myfunc('shimanta');
myManager.logName();
```

Now you have effectively scoped the `name` variable and you don't need to worry about using global variables anymore! To see this working checkout [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58sfeduu/1/).